# GWT: How do I return plain text from my servlet?

Tags: gwt

I'm using GWT 2.4.  I have a form in which I create a submit button 
like so

```
    private Button createSaveButton() { 
            final Button saveButton = new Button("Save"); 
            saveButton.getElement().setAttribute("name", SaveXmlServlet.SAVE_BUTTON_PARAM_NAME); 
            saveButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() { 
                    @Override 
                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) { 
                            formPanel.submit(); 
                    } 
            }); 
            return saveButton; 
    }       // createSaveButton
```

I define an onComplete handler for the form like so

```
            formPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler() { 
                    @Override 
                    public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) { 
                            Window.alert(event.getResults()); 
                    } 
            });
```

The servlet I submit the form to returns results as plain text.

```
            res.setContentType("text/plain"); 
            final PrintWriter out = res.getWriter(); 
            out.print(saveSucceeded); 
            out.close();
```

However, when I actually do the alert, it will attach "<pre>" tags to 
the output.  For example, if the servlet outputs "true", what is 
alerted to the user is "<pre>true</pre>".  How do I get this only to 
output what was written to the response?  I could do some string 
manipulation to remove the "<pre>" tags, but that seems like I'm not 
addressing the core issue. 
Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can do anything about that, but it's easy to work around without weird text manipulations:

```
public String getPlainTextResult(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
  Element label = DOM.createLabel();
  label.setInnerHTML( event.getResults() );
  return label.getInnerText();
}
```

Comment: HTML html = new HTML(event.getResults());return html.getText(); is even easier

Comment: This is NOT the correct answer as the server is returning plain text.

Answer (score 10):

There is [another solution](http://www.artofsolving.com/node/50) - to set content type to `text/html`.

Answer (score 1):

```
response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-2");
```

Try this, just before output. Hope it helps.

Comment: Why should charset help this?